# #Python newbee. I am trying to print number after taking input from user using While loop

Tags: python, while-loop

Python newbie. I am trying to print number after taking input from user using while loop.

my code takes int from user and then runs the loop. after printing the first number the code asks to continue after which the loop will continue.

My code is below:

```
 i = 1
 ans = 'n'
 x = int(input("enter a number to loop: " ))

 while(i<x):
   print('\n')
   print(i, end= " ")
   ans = input('\ndo you want to print the next number? ')
   if ans == 'y':
     i += 1
   else:
    print('thanks')
```

The code is doing and extra loop and then after getting the answer terminates the loop. On top of that on the last loop if the answer is 'n' it keeps running.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add a `break` statement in your code, right before the `print("thanks")` line. That will exit the loop.

```
else:
    break
    print('thanks')
```

Answer (score 0):

All loops will continue unless told to break or become false.
Break and continue are very important in programming. I suggest you read this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm